# SQL-statement for ordering

Tags: android, sql

I would like to order a database - but it doesn't work

is

```
 ORDER BY <Field> ASC
```

the statement for android?

Comment: db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM all WHERE PID LIKE '"+SearchID+"%'"+" ORDER BY PLZ ASC", null)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't "order" a database. However, you can order the query results, with the appropriate query overload.

- `public Cursor query (String table, String[] columns, String selection, String[] selectionArgs, String groupBy, String having, String orderBy)`

  [SQLiteDatabase.query | Android Developers](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#query%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)

For example:

```
db.query("someTable", new String[] { "ColumnA", "ColumnB" }, "WHERE ColumnC = ?",
    new String[] { "ColumnC_Condition" }, "ColumnB", null, "ColumnA");
```

translates into

```
SELECT ColumnA, ColumnB FROM someTable WHERE ColumnC = "ColumnC_Condition" 
    GROUP BY ColumnB ORDER BY ColumnA
```

Comment: yeah, I mean the query results ;) I use db.rawquery and I'm not sure if I can use the order by Statement as I know - but with the description I found a little mistake in a name - now it's working - thanks